# Save colored text from RichTextBox to pdf

Tags: c#, winforms

I got following Problem: 
I have a RichTextBox in WinForms in which I change the color of several lines based on a condition. 
I now want to save the content of the RichTextBox in a PDF using `iTextSharp`. 
 But whenever I open the saved file, I get only black lines, the color is missing
My code:

```
        string str = txt_result.Text;
        string path = "";

        SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
        dlg.Title = "Als PDF speichern";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = dlg.FileName;
        }
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        var output = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

        document.Open();

        document.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(str));


        document.Close();
        writer.Close();
        output.Close();
```

Thank you for your help! 
 
Edit: I already tried `txt_result.rtf` but with RTF I only get cryptic symbols in my file

Comment: maybe this could help you: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570682/PDF-File-Writer-Csharp-Class-Library-Version

Comment: @Raizzen looks like it does not support RichTextBoxes

Comment: If `txt_result` is your RTB you simply don't copy color, just its `Text`. You would have to copy the `Rtf` of it; not sure if iTextSharp supports this, and if so how to do it right. - If not the workaround will be tedious: You will have to recreate the formatting..